# Only specific materials apply to model

Tags: texturing, materials

There are 3 buildings with materials on the screenshot. Buildings 1 and 2 have their own materials and I'm trying to create another material for the 3rd one. For some reason, the 3rd building doesn't show any material assigned to it, except the material used for the 1st building.

**Use cases**

- Create a new material for the 3rd building - doesn't work
- Apply material from the 2nd building to the 3rd building - doesn't work
- Apply material from the 1st building to the 3rd building - works

Any ideas?

**Blend file**

https://pasteall.org/blend/8dc2d5c478e04524882269552c02c34f

[image: New Material]

Comment: are you sure you've assigned the right material to the faces?

Comment: it would help if you tell us step by step what you did/tried, or make a video of this...or provide your blend file and tell us what object is building 1,2 and 3.

Comment: It looks like the two shorter buildings are linked to the same mesh data block. If this is the case, materials will by default be used on both of them. To avoid this but keep mesh data block linking, change the linking from “mesh data” to “object data” in the Material Properties tab next to the material selection pull-down.

Comment: @moonboots Yes. As I mentioned, assigning material #1 to building #3 works fine. Building #3 doesn't show only material from building #2 and the new material.

Comment: please pack your images and share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: @Chris I added a link to blend file and recorded this video https://youtu.be/o0qmBoedhow

Comment: @moonboots Added link to blend file https://pasteall.org/blend/8dc2d5c478e04524882269552c02c34f

Comment: @Anonymous: your video is private...we cannot see it

Comment: @Chris Made public. Could you try now, please? https://youtu.be/o0qmBoedhow

Comment: @TheLabCat Not really. The two short buildings are separate objects but I want to make them look the same, so I created material #2 for building #2 and it worked fine (windows on the wall). When I tried to create similar material for building #3 it didn't show up in the rendered view.

Comment: you have to tap on assign after you chose the other material....looks like you want just assign some material to some faces, right?

Comment: @Chris Yes, I'd like to assign a new material to several faces, but assign didn't work. There is a small catch. These models were generated by OSM addon and by default it assigns default materials to models. To replace default materials I removed them in the blender file, created new one and assigned to the model. That worked for two buildings but not for the last one.

Comment: Your building has 2 UV maps, maybe make sure that you are using the one you want, the first one? If it is not your problme, could you please pack your images (File > External Data > Pack All Into .blend), only keep the buildings you are talking about and share your file again?

Comment: @moonboots Thank you. You are right. The problem was caused by UV maps. After removing both and performing "Unwrap" and "Assign" I can see material on the model. Could you post this as the answer, so I could close the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 UV Maps and you've selected the bad one, so the texture is not what you're expecting, just select the right one:

[image]